# Find and replace entire value in R

Tags: regex, r, replace

I'm looking for a way to use the find and replace function in R to replace the entire value of a string, rather than just the matching part of the string. I have a dataset with a lot of (very) long names, and I'm looking for an efficient way to find and change their values.

So, for instance, I tried to change this entire string

```
string <- "Generally.speaking..do.you.prefer.to.try.out.new.experiences.like.trying.things.and.meeting.new.people..or.do.you.prefer.familiar.situations.and.faces."
```

to

```
"exp"
```

with this code

```
string <- gsub("experiences", "exp", string)
```

However, this results in substituting "exp" with only the part of string that matches "experiences", and it leaves the rest of the long name intact (bolded for clarity):

> "Generally.speaking..do.you.prefer.to.try.out.new.**exp**..like.trying.things.and.meeting.new.people..or.do.you.prefer.familiar.situations.and.faces."

In this case, because the string contains "experiences", it should be replaced with "exp."

Is there a way to tell gsub or some other function to replace the entire value? I looked a lot of tutorials and it seems like functions only operate within a string or on whole values, but not between the two.

Comment: So, if "experiences" is found, return "exp", otherwise return the entire string?

Comment: @rawr that got much closer! but a lot of the string name is still left intact.

Comment: @frank yes. so, only replace the value if the pattern is found in the string. I'll be searching through a lot of long-named values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `gsub` as follows:

```
 gsub(".*experiences.*", "exp", string, perl=TRUE) 
 # As @rawr notes, set perl=TRUE for improved efficiency
```

This regex matches strings that have any characters 0 or more times (i.e. `.*`) followed by "experiences", followed by any characters 0 or more times.

In this case, you are still replacing the entire match with "exp" but by using regex, you expand the definition of the match (from "experience" to ".*experience.*") to achieve the desired substitution.

Comment: Hmmm, so maybe I didn't create a good example. The replace that i'm doing on my dataset uses 'gsub("*.experiences.*", "exp", names(fs)', where names(fs) is vector of columns of all header names. When i apply the code to vector, it results in only a partial replacement of the string value ""Generally.speaking..do.you.prefer.to.try.out.newexp"" . I have no idea why a column vector would be different.

Comment: that worked! good eye other frank! question for learning purpose: what does .* do? i'm somewhat familiar with regular expressions and i don't recognize that

Comment: Oh, `.` is "any character" and `*` is "any number of times" :) Sorry, I deleted my comment already, thinking it was wrong. By the way, backticks (on the tilde button on my keyboard) are for code-formatting inside comments.

Answer (score 7):

There's no need to modify the string with `gsub` since you know the desired value ("exp").

```
s = c(string,"bah","egad.experiences")

replace(s,grep("experiences",s),"exp")
# [1] "exp" "bah" "exp"
```

---

**Speed.** This is a little faster than the string modification in other@Frank's answer.

(Thanks to @rawr for pointing out that we should both turn on perl parsing.)

```
ss <- c(replicate(1e6,s))
system.time(replace(ss,grep("experiences",ss,perl=TRUE),"exp"))
#    user  system elapsed 
#     0.6     0.0     0.6 
system.time(gsub(".*experiences.*", "exp", ss,perl=TRUE))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    2.39    0.00    2.38
```

Taking away the replacement operations in each answer, it looks like the different patterns being matched make up most of the difference (contrary to what I had expected, seen in my last edit):

```
system.time(grep("experiences",ss,perl=TRUE))     # used in my answer
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.64    0.00    0.64
system.time(grep(".*experiences.*",ss,perl=TRUE)) # used in purple-gravatar @Frank's answer
#    user  system elapsed 
#    1.82    0.00    1.82
```

Comment: Nice point about the speed differences involved with string replacement vs modification!

Comment: I'm no Frank, but if you use `perl = TRUE` in  `system.time(gsub(".*experiences.*", "exp", ss))`, it will be about twice as fast, for me at least

Comment: @rawr Frankly, that's another good point on efficiency. - Frank (purple)

Comment: @rawr Thanks; added. Frankness and optimality do not always coincide, alas. With perl on, my last point is reversed, so I've also substantially edited that.

Answer (score 1):

`gsub()` is used to substitute a particular string with another string. In the above code, if you do the following, your whole string changes to `exp`

```
result <- gsub(string, "exp", string)
```

But, if you use `grep()` and `replace()`, you will achieve your desired result.

```
res1 <- grep("pattern",string)
```

gives you all the lines with the pattern and use this in `replace()`.

```
res_new <- replace(string,res1,"exp")
```

Comment: as i mentioned above, I guess i screwed up in creating my example. I'm applying to gsub to names(df), so that r looks through a vector of header names for a string with the pattern match and replaces just that object. Your code works on this example, but not on a vector from a dataframe. I didn't know such a different existed, but i should have created a better example

Comment: As @Frank(green gravatar) suggests, sapply or looping is unnecessary here. Thanks for pointing that replace() takes vector :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply use `gsub()` and add `.*` before and after the pattern like this:

```
string<-"TransRights"
gsub(".*sR.*","HumanRights",string)
```

The outcome would be

```
HumanRights
```